# Does Booker's ship (or its parts) have any particular shape?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In Discovery's season 3, Booker's vessel appears to change its shape frequently during action sequences. This is usually visualized as various components flying around and reattaching in different configurations.

Unfortunately, these scenes are usually very fast and dynamic, so it's hard to see any details.

Does the ship have any particular shape, or consist of a fixed set of components that are rearranged in multiple ways? Or does the shape even of the individual components change at will, using a similar technology as the computer terminals inside?

Comment: Programmable matter?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: Yes, that's what I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know how Book's ship works in its entirety, but from what we've seen

1. Book seems to prefer the slight "C" shape we most commonly see it in

   [image: The C shape]
2. We don't see the parts break up like programmable matter. Instead, they seem to be able to somehow disconnect and reform without losing cohesion

   [image: Disassembly]

We know from several episodes that the cockpit is one of these indivisible units. We've not seen anything that indicates the parts change shape  but S3E12 shows that it can be made far more compact by moving what are presumably cargo pods inside the main warp module.

[image: Breaking Apart]

[image: Compacted]

There's never been any "sand" particle effects that are indicative of programmable matter

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as - at the current state of the series - this reflects our current canon knowledge about the ship. (In any case, I think it was an unwise decision from a merchandising point of view ;) )

Comment: Yeah [toys about transforming stuff](https://transformers.hasbro.com/en-us/toys-products) will never work :P

Comment: Both a humanoid robot and the vehicles those robots can transform into are very recognizeable shapes. I would hesitate to describe Booker's ship as "recognizeable" even in its standard configuration, let alone any of the other configurations that often only appeared for a few moments. Add to that that I was thinking more along the lines of model kits to put in your display case rather than interactive toys, and I think you see where I'm coming from.